# What do you call (too) elaborate words and expressions?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call (too) elaborate words and expressions? Like when you use literary words no one really uses or intricate comparisons (like, if you watched the TV series The Walking Dead, the way Eugene speaks, see the quote). I know 'flourish' can work to an extent, but I'm not happy with it still.

> I didn't mean to intrude, but I felt it incumbent upon my person to give you a once-over after seeing you take a cherry cheesecake like that to the kisser.

*(from [here](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=36076))*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is

> **flowery**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **1.2** (of speech or writing) full of elaborate or literary words and phrases.
>
> *You may be able to turn my mother and sister's heads with your flowery speeches but not mine.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/flowery), also synonyms such as [**grandiloquent**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/grandiloquent).